# Import Excel table to SQL by overwritting

Tags: sql, database, excel, csv

I have an Excel file that maps exactly to a table in SQL Server. I have tried to import but I get the UNIQUE KEY error.

How can I overwrite the exisitng values in the database table with those in the excel file? I can convert to csv. if this is any help. Is there a statement I can write to do this?

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a second table using the same DDL as that table (in the database).
2. Afterward, import the Excel file into that newly created table.
3. Delete from the actual table (not the one just created above) all rows where the columns making up the unique key constraint match that of the the rows newly inserted into the newly created table.
4. Then insert into the actual table all rows that exist in the second, newly created and populated table. Because you just deleted the rows with the values you want to overwrite, you will no longer violate the unique constraint.

If you provide the column names of your table and the column(s) that make up the unique constraint I can help you write the query for #3 if needed.

Step 3 would be something like:

```
delete from table_name
 where unique_id in
       (select unique_id from newly_created_table_in_step1_and_2)
```

Comment: so if i write a query in the form of:
    `SELECT * FROM database`
    `WHERE uniqueid = 'XXXXXXX, XXXXXXX, XXXXXXX',`

    `DELETE FROM database`
    `WHERE uniqueid = '12345, 12346, 12347', `

Am i on the right track? I think I will vlookup ids against an export of that table to obtain the values.

Comment: @user3845582 if the unique constraint is only on one field then yes, however for multiple values you would use IN ('x','y','z')

Answer (score 0):

Please display the whole ERRO. if you have UNIQUE KEY Error then you have to create update query using primary key. you might have to write TSQL query.